# How to get dynamically generated check box values

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to get the values of Dynamically generated CheckBoxes using jquery

```
for(i=startAt;i<limit;i++)
{
    var str = '<tr>'+
              '<td width="48" align="center"><input class="A" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value='+ local[i]['_id'] +'></td>'+
              '<td width="270" >' + local[i]['_id'] +'</td>'+
              '<td width="883" class="alignRt">'+local[i]['count']+'</td>'+
              '</tr>'
            $("#tableBody").append(str);
}
```

using this I am able to get the total checkboxes at runtime

```
$(document).on('click', '.A', function(){
var n = $("input:checked.A").length;
console.log(n)
```

But I want to get the values too.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You are generating invalid HTML, ids must be *unique*

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: if i remove id than too i want to get the values of all generated checkboxes as soon as they get clicked @Quentin

Comment: use `.class` instead.

Comment: @ Quentin i have updated the code i want the values at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
jQuery('.A:checked')
```

You can then loop over the elements to get all their values.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', '.A', function(){

    var n = $( "input:checked.A" ).length;
    var arr=[]
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        arr.push($($( "input:checked.A" )[i]).val())
    }
    alert(arr)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get checked checkboxes using:

```
$("#tableBody").find("input:checked");
```

It returns a list of checked checkboxes

Answer (score -1):

use JQuery's `$('#CheckboxID').val()`

Comment: That won't work — http://jsbin.com/ehewec/1/edit — You aren't limiting matches to *checked* inputs, the selector will only match a single element (and the question wants *all* the checked checkboxes), and even if it did; `val()` will only return the value of the first matching element.